# How to select 200 record for each 'for loop' iteration in oracle?

Tags: oracle, plsql

What i want is this .

I have a table with 10000 record like this

```
Table A

user_id | name | rollno | state
```

What i want is to select 200 record at once and then next 200 in next iteration and so on . What i can thought of is this.

```
.... declare statement


     SELECT count(*) into v_length from A;
        i := 0;
         FOR i into v_length /200  loop

             FOR rec IN (SELECT b.blurb_id, b.article_source_clob, row_number() over(ORDER BY b.blurb_id) myrow
                              FROM mobile.mobile_blurb b)
                        WHERE myrow < i*200 and myrow > (i+1)*200 )  loop
             ............. and 200 record every time
         end loops;

... end
```

Comment: Why do you need to split the processing?

Comment: The reason is i have to send data outside the database by http ? And i have to do that by oracle only . 10000 record at a time takes  too much time .

Comment: You can use `BULK COLLECT` with `LIMIT` clause

Comment: No other way other then using cursor @XING .

Comment: @Himanshusharma Thats the efficient way. Why do you want someother way when you have a efficient way

Comment: Just to know other solution . your solution will work fine . You want to add answer or i add answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in my comments, you can use `BULK` collect and `LIMIT` option to achieve your requirement. See below demo. Here in each time the loop will run and pick `200` records.

```
DECLARE
   CURSOR rec
   IS
          SELECT LEVEL
            FROM DUAL
      CONNECT BY LEVEL < 401;

   TYPE v_var IS TABLE OF NUMBER
      INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;

   var   v_var;
BEGIN
   OPEN rec;

   LOOP
      FETCH rec BULK COLLECT INTO var LIMIT 200;

      EXIT WHEN (var.count = 0);

      FOR i IN 1 .. var.COUNT
      LOOP
         DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (var (i));
      END LOOP;
   END LOOP;

   CLOSE rec;
END;
```